# Chrome extension popups not displaying on second monitor

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu

Since I have upgraded to Windows 10 none of my chrome extensions are displaying popups when their icons are clicked and sometimes a small corner of the popup will display. I have discovered that when the window is on my main screen that the popups work fine (I have a 3 monitor setup).

I have tried many versions of Chrome and Chrome canary, 32 and 64 bit and all have this problem. I have also tried changing various GPU related flags but have had no luck with this either.

My video card is a GTX590 and as this is a dual GPU card it may explain why the popups are only seen on the monitor connected to GPU A and not the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a solution, but a workaround:
Go into advanced settings and uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when availible"

I ran into the same problem. Not sure if this is caused by a GPU driver problem of NVidia, SLI config problem, second Monitor driver problem or a Chrome problem.

Comment: I'm skeptical of this being a solution. Sounds more like an issue of which monitor is set to primary or not. If they are displaying at all anywhere, it's not a hardware acceleration issue. Also from what I recall about browser hardware acceleration, I think it only effects rendered content - not system popups.

Comment: @Enigma It seems to fix the problem however. I would assume there is a Chrome bug where it doesn't properly display the popup on a different GPU.

Comment: @Enigma I partially agree with you, Ive updated my answer, it is however affecting all extension popups, for example: AdBlock plus or Google ChromeCast, Im using a dual monitor setup

Answer (score 1):

I saw this issue on Chrome stable - 49.0.2623.87 (and many previous versions). Disbling hardware acceleration does the trick. However I use also Chrome Canary (51.0.2679.4) and there I have hardware acceleration enabled and on both screens popups show correctly. 
I just hope Chrome team fixed this issue.